# UITableViewCell Constraint in iOS 8 not working in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios8, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have used the Autolayout in iOS 7 and it works correctly without any problems but regarding to iOS8 it isn't worked at all .

Can i used the same UITableViewCell constraint for iOS7 and iOS 8 ?

Comment: Please provide more details. What exactly isn't working? Screenshots?

Comment: I have multiple issues with autolayout specially in UITableViewCell , what i need to know is there a basic which can i used when implement autolayout in iOS 8 rather than iOS 7 , also if you have full example support iOS 7 & iOS 8 .

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: Please provide more details, code/screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced, that on iOS 8 some things just don't work as they did in iOS 7. For example, I had a Tableview with a few custom cells. Everything worked fine in the iOS 8 simulator, but on a iOS 7 device the tableview was always empty and the cellForRowAtIndexPath function was never called. It turned out to be a problem with Autolayout. Everything I had to do was to set correct constraints for the whole tableview, not just the cells. So my advice would be to check ALL constraints used in your view, not just the ones you think could be messed up.

Comment: I Need more obvious details

Comment: Well, you didn't provide any details as well. Based on how your question is formulated, I can only tell you to look through all of your constraints in your Tableviewcontroller and Tableviewcell again and maybe try to remove and add them again. You could also try to click on "Reset to suggested constraints" or "Add missing constraints". Make sure to add Width+Height Constraints or the Margin Constraints. And what do you exactly mean by "Constraint is not working"?

Comment: I have used programmatically constraints

Comment: Then maybe try to use the visual ones in your storyboard. At least for debugging.